# How can I make my dotfiles public with a private fork or repository?

Tags: git, terminal, dotfiles

I want to make my dotfiles public. I found {Yadm](https://thelocehiliosan.github.io/yadm/) which looks to be what I want.

Secret data I don't really want in version control at all. I'll store this offline on a USB stick somewhere (ssh keys, gpg keys, etc.). However, there are other files which contain information I want to filter out or change before making public.

Yadm also allows me to have [alternate files](https://thelocehiliosan.github.io/yadm/docs/alternates) within the same repository, so I am thinking [this design is what I should go with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onoAM.png), rather than [separate branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfFO6.png).

The reason for having a private repository is because certain files like `irc.conf` have strings I want to substitute or sanitize. I might want to include this file, but delete all lines that contain `SECRET_IRC_NETWORK`.

```
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.addresses = "irc.secret.example.com"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl = on
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl_cert = "~/.weechat/ssl/SECRET_IRC/SECRET_IRC-SECRET_NAME.pem"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl_priorities = "NORMAL:-VERS-SSL3.0"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl_dhkey_size
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl_fingerprint = "SECRET_FINGERPRINT"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.ssl_verify = on
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.sasl_username = "SECRET_USERNAME"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.nicks = "SECRET_NAME"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.username = "SECRET_USERNAME"
~/.weechat/irc.conf:SECRET_IRC_NETWORK.realname = "SECRET_NAME"
```

Another example might be my iptables rules configuration `rules6-save`:

```
~/etc/iptables/rules6-save:-A INPUT -s `2001:MY:SECRET:ASSIGNED:RANGE::/64 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I would want to substitute `2001:MY:SECRET:ASSIGNED:RANGE` with `2001:db8:AAA:AAA:AAA::/64` before it goes public. Is https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes "filter driver" how I do this?

1. Do I need to commit to the public repository (red), or the private fork (green)?

I figure it would work like this:

- Comitting to the private repo
- Filtering and pushing to public repo (being very careful to check everything is correctly sanitized)

or

- Cherry pick some commit from public
- Filtering and merging with private

  2. From my research, if you have a public repository on Github/Gitlab you cannot have a private fork and make any pull requests from it. Ideally the private one would be on my own private server.

How can I get around this? I don't want people to know the private fork exists. Therefore it would be important that any commits from the private fork have the author also sanitized.

(Above diagram dot file).

```
digraph graphname {
    node [shape=rectangle, style="filled"];

    dotfiles [fillcolor="#ff9999", label="master (public) \n Desktop, laptop, workstation, server, vm"];
    friendsworkstation [fillcolor="#ffffbb", label="Friend's Workstation (private)"]
    prFromFriend [fillcolor="#ff9999", label="Friend opens PR (public)"]
    { rank=same dotfilesPrivate friendsworkstation prFromFriend }

    dotfilesPrivate [fillcolor="#99ff99", label="master (private) \n Desktop, laptop, workstation, server, vm"]

    dotfiles -> dotfilesPrivate
    dotfiles -> friendsworkstation
    dotfilesPrivate -> dotfiles
    prFromFriend -> dotfiles
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up solving this. Esentially what I did was used YADM's bootstrap option. I created a bootstrap template [`bootstrap##yadm.j2`](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/.yadm/bootstrap%23%23yadm.j2)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SUBMODULE_INIT_VIM=`jq '.submodule_init_vim' ~/.yadm/bootstrap_vars.json`

{% if YADM_CLASS == 'Workstation' -%}
    SSH_HOSTS=$(cat ~/template_data/ssh/hosts.json) envtpl --keep-template ~/.ssh/config##Workstation.tpl -o ~/.ssh/config
    SEC=$(cat ~/template_data/weechat/sec.json) PASSPHRASE='tiddles' envtpl --keep-template ~/.weechat/sec.conf##Workstation.tpl -o ~/.weechat/sec.conf
    SERVERS=$(cat ~/template_data/weechat/servers.json) envtpl --keep-template ~/.weechat/irc.conf##Workstation.tpl -o ~/.weechat/irc.conf
    PATHS=$(cat ~/template_data/shell/path.json##Workstation.Linux) envtpl --keep-template ~/.bashrc##Workstation.Linux.tpl -o ~/.bashrc
    if [ $SUBMODULE_INIT_VIM = "true" ]; then
        vim '+PlugUpdate' '+PlugClean!' '+PlugUpdate' '+qall'
    elif [ $SUBMODULE_INIT_VIM = "false" ]; then
        echo "Not initalizing submodules for vim"
    fi
RUN_PACKAGE_MANAGER=`jq '.run_package_manager' ~/.yadm/bootstrap_vars.json`
if [ $RUN_PACKAGE_MANAGER = "true" ]; then
    {% if YADM_DISTRO == 'Arch' -%}
    PACMAN_PACKAGES=(`jq -r 'join(" ")' ~/template_data/packages/pacman.json`)
    echo "Running sudo pacman -Syu" ${PACMAN_PACKAGES[@]}
    sudo pacman -Syu ${PACMAN_PACKAGES[@]}
    if [ -f /usr/bin/yay ]; then
        YAY_PACKAGES=(`jq -r 'join(" ")' ~/template_data/packages/yay.json`)
        echo "Running yay -Syu" ${YAY_PACKAGES[@]}
        yay -Syu ${PACMAN_PACKAGES[@]}
    else
        echo "Yay doesn't exist"
    fi{%
    elif YADM_DISTRO == 'Debian' -%}
    APT_PACKAGES=(`jq -r 'join(" ")' ~/template_data/packages/debian.json`)
    echo "Running sudo apt-get install" ${APT_PACKAGES[@]}
    sudo apt-get install ${APT_PACKAGES[@]}
    {% else -%}echo "Unknown distribution"{% endif %}
elif [ $RUN_PACKAGE_MANAGER = "false" ]; then
echo "Not installing any packages"
fi
{% elif YADM_CLASS == 'Router' -%}
    MY_RANGE='2001:db8:AAA:AAA:AAA' envtpl --keep-template ~/.config/etc/iptables/rules6-save##Router.tpl -o ~/.config/etc/iptables/rules6-save
{% elif YADM_CLASS == 'VirtualMachine' -%}
   echo "NOTE: Some configs for virtual machines"
{% else -%}
   echo "ERROR: Unknown class selected"
{% endif -%}
```

I created some [bootstrapping variables](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/.yadm/bootstrap_vars.json) and read them in with jq. This allowed me to skip certain parts of the initialization.

```
{
  "submodule_init_vim": false,
  "run_package_manager": true
}
```

I template-atized many of my configuration files and put the template data in [`~/template_data`](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/tree/master/template_data).

If you look at my [.bashrc config](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc%23%23Workstation.Linux.tpl) you can see how I read in the path:

```
export PATH="{% for v in PATHS | from_json %}{{v.path |join(':')}}{% endfor %}"
```

Which takes in the data from the [`/template_data/shell/path.json##Linux`](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/template_data/shell/path.json%23%23Workstation.Linux).

```
[
    {"path": ["/usr/local/sbin",
              "/usr/local/bin",
              "/usr/sbin",
              "/usr/bin",
              "/sbin",
              "/bin",
              "/usr/libexec",
              "$HOME/.local/bin"]
    }
]
```

This was a simple example, but I did the same for my [SSH hosts too](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/.ssh/config%23%23Workstation.tpl#L20).

```
{% for v in SSH_HOSTS | from_json %}{%
    if v.Host != '' %}Host {{ v.Host }}{%
    endif %}{%
    if v.Comment != '' %}
    {{ v.Comment }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.Hostname != '' %}
    Hostname {{ v.Hostname }}{%
    endif %}{%
    if v.Port != '' %}
    Port {{ v.Port }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.User != '' %}
    User {{ v.User }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.HostKeyAlgorithms != '' %}
    HostKeyAlgorithms {{ v.HostKeyAlgorithms }}{%
    endif %}{%
    if v.KexAlgorithms != '' %}
    KexAlgorithms {{ v.KexAlgorithms }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.Ciphers != '' %}
    Ciphers {{ v.Ciphers }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.MACs != '' %}
    MACs {{ v.MACs }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.PasswordAuthentication != '' %}
    PasswordAuthentication {{ v.PasswordAuthentication }}{% endif %}{%
    if v.IdentifyFile != '' %}
    IdentityFile {{ v.IdentifyFile }}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Where I read in the template data from [`template_data/ssh/hosts.json`](https://github.com/thingfox/dotfiles/blob/master/template_data/ssh/hosts.json)

```
[
    {
        "Host":"NSA",
        "Comment": "# Compute with world's dick pix",
        "Hostname":"203.0.113.1",
        "Port": "",
        "User": "nsa",
        "HostKeyAlgorithms":"",
        "KexAlgorithms": "",
        "Ciphers": "",
        "MACs":"",
        "PasswordAuthentication": "",
        "IdentifyFile":"~/.ssh/id_ed25519_nsa"
    },
    {
        "Host":"CIA",
        "Comment": "",
        "Hostname":"203.0.113.2",
        "Port": "",
        "User": "cia",
        "HostKeyAlgorithms":"",
        "KexAlgorithms": "",
        "Ciphers": "",
        "MACs":"",
        "PasswordAuthentication": "",
        "IdentifyFile":"~/.ssh/id_ed25519_cia"
    }
]
```